# how to execute script from python with options

Tags: python-3.x, executable

I need to run the following command via python.

`/work/data/get_info name=Mike home`

The error I am getting is `No such file or directory: '/work/data/get_info name=Mike home'`.  Which isn't correct.  the get_info program does exits.
It is working in a perl script I am trying to get the same functionality in python.

perl script

```
$ENV{work} = '/work/data';
my $myinfo = "$ENV{work}/bin/get_info";
$info = `$myinfo name=Mike home`;
```

Info dumps out information

my python script

```
import os, subprocess

os.environ['work'] = '/work/data'
run_info = "{}/bin/get_info name={} {}".format(os.environ['work'],'Mike','home')
p = subprocess.call([run_product_info], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

I get an error `No such file or directory: '/work/data/get_info name=Mike`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python `subprocess.call` is thinking that the entire string is the name of the program, as if you had double quoted it like `"/work/data/get_info name=Mike home"` since you passed it as an array.

Either pass it without the array for the shell (if you are sure all escaping/quoting is correct, and see warnings in the docs) or pass each as a separate array element.

```
subprocess.call(['/work/data/bin/get_info', 'name=Mike', 'home'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.call('/work/data/bin/get_info name=Mike home', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.